# Metro icon in medium tile size for windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I want the metro icons like **(appbar.edit.png , appbar.add.png)**  in the midium tile size.
Which are standard icons of windows phone 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've installed the SDK you'll find the provided app bar icons at "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.0\Icons\Dark\".
These are only provided at the size appropriate for use in the app bar (76x76 pixels) because that's what they are intended to be used for.

If you're looking for icons for use in the application bar or anywhere else in your app, including tiles, check out these sources (most of which include scalable versions of the images provided with the SDK):

[Metro Studio 2](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/metrostudio) (By SyncFusion)
[The Noun Project](http://thenounproject.com/)
[Modern UI Icons](http://modernuiicons.com/)
[iconmonstr](http://iconmonstr.com/)

Comment: thanks its usefull for me. these links show "light" icons but i want the "dark" icons.

Comment: @Sandy You'll find the other versions of the SDK provided files at  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.0\Icons\Light\". If you've got files from elsewhere you can always edit them